# I am looking for some help on remeshing an imported STL

Tags: remesh

[image]I have imported an STL and, as expected, the mesh is triangular. I am trying to understand the remesh function and not getting results I am after. I thought the remesh turned the mesh into quads?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the *Remesh Mode* to *Block*, then go into wireframe mode and then change the *Octree Depth* up til it looks like the mesh before.

Be careful though as it can slow down your computer (treat it like a *Subdivision* modifier). Then apply it and you should have quad geometry.